# Critical destructive vs. critical constructive

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, math-history

I was reading the book *Men of Mathematics* by E. T. Bell and at the beginning of chapter two I encountered the following paragraph:

> Zeno and Eudoxus are representative of two vigorous opposing schools
> of mathematical thought which flourish today, the critical-destructive
> and the critical-constructive. Both had minds as penetratingly
> critical as their successors in the nineteenth and twentieth
> centuries. This statement can of course be inverted: Kronecker
> ($1823$-$1891$) and Brouwer ($1881$- ), the modern critics of mathematical
> analysis—the theories of the infinite and the continuous—are as
> ancient as Zeno; the creators of the modern theories of continuity and
> the infinite, Weierstrass ($1815$-$1897$), Dedekind ($1831$-$1916$), and
> Cantor ($1845$-$1918$) are intellectual contemporaries of Eudoxus.

What does he means by critical-destructive and critical-constructive$?$ I know applied calculus but I have not studied mathematical analysis yet. Could you please explain the above terms in a rather simple language$?$

Comment: You might enjoy reading *The Mathematical Experience* by Davis and Hersh, which discusses that kind of thing, if I remember correctly

Comment: I’ve not run into the specific terms elsewhere, but the context suggests that Bell is drawing a distinction between the kind of mathematical creativity that finds ways to do things rigorously and the kind that finds areas in which rigor is lacking and needs to be developed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So which one is which$?$

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: I listed the constructive first.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks a lot.